# Silverlight has no Math.Truncate! ...will this equivalent work?

Tags: silverlight, math

Does this work as an equivalent for `Math.Truncate` in most/all cases:

```
double x = 1034.45
var truncated = x - Math.Floor(Math.Abs(x));
```

where `truncated == 0.45`?

**Update...**

Thanks for the input people! This is working for me:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldTruncateNumber()
{
    double x = -1034.068;
    double truncated = ((x < 0) ? -1 : 1) * Math.Floor(Math.Abs(x));

    Assert.AreEqual(Math.Truncate(x), truncated, "The expected truncated number is not here");
}
```

This too:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldGetMantissa()
{
    double x = -1034.068;
    double mantissaValue = ((x < 0) ? -1 : 1) *
        (Math.Abs(x) - Math.Floor(Math.Abs(x)));
    mantissaValue = Math.Round(mantissaValue, 2);

    Assert.AreEqual(-0.07, mantissaValue, "The expected mantissa decimal is not here");
}
```

Comment: Obviously not, since the presence of `Abs` means that no negative result is possible, whereas `Truncate` can return negative results.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oops! I used to get my math test questions in college wrong for leaving out the negative ;)

Comment: You're updated examples are "interesting" - but I'd recommend adopting @JoachimIsaksson's answer as a building block - it performs the correct truncate function (and then you just need to multiple/divide to get decimal places as you want them)

Comment: Yup actually I'm getting the mantissa not the conventional truncation---which is not very "interesting" to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this functionality was introduced in Silverlight 4 or if we simply just missed it, but `Decimal` has an static method for `Truncate`

```
public double Truncate(double d)
{
    return Convert.ToDouble(Decimal.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(d)));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `truncated` won't get the correct value for negative values of `x`.

To use Math.Floor to round toward zero like Truncate does, just do;

```
static double Truncate(double d)
{
    return d > 0 ? Math.Floor(d) : -Math.Floor(-d);
}
```